# Get all logged in user from session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an old application developed in asp.net mvc 5 using C#, the authentication of user is being manage by using session variable, now I want to know all the logged in users & their identity based on session created.

Is it possible to capture all the users who logged in on real time basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users are stored in the Session, you could simply loop through the Session and look for all stored users:

```
foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
    var sessionObject = Session[key];
    // Check if the object is a user and add to a count variable
}
```